# Delphi FMX: rendering YUV image on a TForm3D/component using GPU programming

Tags: delphi, directx, firemonkey, direct3d, yuv

I am trying to render YUV images on a FMX Form. I have been studying the following examples: https://github.com/grijjy/JustAddCode/tree/master/GpuProgramming

I have managed to render YUVNV12 and YUV420 images (which I decode from video files using FFMPEG library) using Delphi VCL + Direct3D. In case of VCL, I can find enough examples in C/C++ code which I can translate to Delphi (VCL).

I tried the following to render (YUV) images:

1. SDL2 library: works fine on VCL. Unusable on Android together with Delphi.
2. [PXL library](https://asphyre.net/products/pxl): works fine on Windows and Android (I am not able to test on other platforms: iOS, macOS...) except I need to convert YUV -> RGB before rendering. This is too slow on Android (phone/tablet).
3. Delphi VCL project using DirectX API calls, converted source from C/C++ examples which works fine up to HD (rec.709) images. I was not able yet to render images with HDR (rec.2020) images.

The final goal to be achieved is rendering YUV images without converting them to RGB/BGR via CPU on a FMX Form/Component, so it will be usable on multiple platforms.

In the example "03Texture", I added 2 textures: 1 for Y-plane and 1 for UV-plane:

```
property TextureY : TTexture read FTextureY   write SetTextureY;
property TextureUV: TTexture read FTextureUV  write SetTextureUV;
```

I made some changes in procedure "HandleImageChanged":

```
procedure TImageMaterialSource.HandleImageChanged(Sender: TObject);
begin
//TImageMaterial(Material).Texture := TTexture.Create;
//TImageMaterial(Material).Texture.PixelFormat := FMX.types.tpixelformat.a;
if n12 <> nil
then begin
  if TImageMaterial(Material).TextureY = nil
  then begin
    TImageMaterial(Material).TextureY := TTexture.Create;
    TImageMaterial(Material).TextureY.PixelFormat := FMX.types.tpixelformat.L;
    TImageMaterial(Material).TextureY.SetSize(n12.pitch, n12.height);
  end;
  if TImageMaterial(Material).TextureUV = nil
  then begin
    TImageMaterial(Material).TextureUV := TTexture.Create;
    TImageMaterial(Material).TextureUV.PixelFormat := FMX.types.tpixelformat.LA;
    TImageMaterial(Material).TextureUV.SetSize(n12.pitch, n12.height div 2);
  end;

  TImageMaterial(Material).TextureY.UpdateTexture(n12.Y, n12.width);
  TImageMaterial(Material).TextureUV.UpdateTexture(n12.UV, n12.width);
end;
```

As you can see I am trying to update Y and UV textures hoping that they are being sent to the GPU. I used "FMX.types.tpixelformat.L -> 1byte" for *textureY* for which I used `DXGI_FORMAT_R8_UNORM` on my VCL code for DirectX. For *textureUV*, "FMX.types.tpixelformat.LA - 2bytes" <- `DXGI_FORMAT_R8G8_UNORM` - I don't know if these are good choices but just for trying...

Vertex shader:

```
struct VS_INPUT                
{                              
    float4 Pos : POSITION;     
    float2 Tex : TEXCOORD;     
};                             
                           
struct VS_OUTPUT               
{                              
   float4 Pos : SV_POSITION;  
   float2 Tex : TEXCOORD;     
};                             
VS_OUTPUT main(VS_INPUT input) 
{                              
  return input;               
}
```

PixelShader:

```
Texture2D Texture;                                      
Texture2D TextureY;                                     
Texture2D TextureUV;                                    
SamplerState theSampler;                                
                                                     
struct PixelShaderInput                                 
{                                                       
   float4 pos : SV_POSITION;                          
   float2 tex : TEXCOORD0;                            
   float4 color : COLOR0;                             
};                                                     
                                                     
float4 main(PixelShaderInput input) : SV_TARGET       
{                                                       
  const float3 offset = {0.0, -0.501960814, -0.501960814};
  const float3 Rcoeff = {1.0000,  0.0000,  1.4020};       
  const float3 Gcoeff = {1.0000, -0.3441, -0.7141};       
  const float3 Bcoeff = {1.0000,  1.7720,  0.0000};       
  float4 Output;                                          
  float3 yuv;                                             
  yuv.x = TextureY.Sample(theSampler, input.tex).x;       
  yuv.yz = TextureUV.Sample(theSampler, input.tex).yz;    
  yuv += offset;                                          
  Output.r = dot(yuv, Rcoeff);                            
  Output.g = dot(yuv, Gcoeff);                            
  Output.b = dot(yuv, Bcoeff);                            
  Output.a = 1.0f;                                        
  //return Output * input.color;                          
  return float4(Output);                                  
 //return Texture.Sample(Sampler, input.tex);          
}
```

function for reading a NV12 file:

```
PNV12Frame = ^TNV12Frame;
TNV12Frame = record
  width,
  height,
  pitch:Cardinal;
  Y:PByte;
  UV:PByte;
end;

function ReadNV12FromFile(fn:TFileName):PNV12Frame;
var f:TFileStream;
    xsize,
    readBytes:Integer;
    nv12Frame:PNV12Frame;
begin
  f := TFileStream.Create(fn, fmOpenRead);
  //FILE *file = nullptr;
  //sprintf_s(buf, "content\\16.nv12");
  //fopen_s(&file, buf, "rb");

  xsize := sizeof(TNV12Frame);
  nv12Frame := GetMemory(xsize);
  FillChar(nv12Frame^, xsize, 0);
  //readBytes := fread(nv12Frame, size, 1, file);
  f.Position := 0;
  readBytes := f.Read(nv12frame^, xsize);

  xsize := nv12Frame.pitch * nv12Frame.height;
  nv12Frame.Y := GetMemory(xsize); //(BYTE *)malloc(size);
  readBytes := f.ReadData(nv12Frame.Y, xsize);

  xsize := nv12Frame.pitch * nv12Frame.height div 2;
  nv12Frame.UV := GetMemory(xsize);  //(BYTE *)malloc(size);
  readBytes := f.ReadData(nv12Frame.UV, xsize);
  f.Free;
//fclose(file);

  Result := nv12Frame;
end;
```

How to set / do I need to set/ any equalent of the following which are used on (VCL D3D) API calls?

```
const vertexDesc:array[0..2] of D3D11_INPUT_ELEMENT_DESC  =
(
    ( SemanticName:'POSITION' ;SemanticIndex: 0;Format: DXGI_FORMAT_R32G32B32_FLOAT   
;InputSlot: 0; AlignedByteOffset:  0; InputSlotClass: D3D11_INPUT_PER_VERTEX_DATA; 
InstanceDataStepRate: 0 ),
    ( SemanticName:'TEXCOORD' ;SemanticIndex: 0;Format: DXGI_FORMAT_R32G32_FLOAT      
;InputSlot: 0; AlignedByteOffset: 12; InputSlotClass: D3D11_INPUT_PER_VERTEX_DATA; 
InstanceDataStepRate: 0 ),
    ( SemanticName:'COLOR'    ;SemanticIndex: 0;Format: 
DXGI_FORMAT_R32G32B32A32_FLOAT;InputSlot: 0; AlignedByteOffset: 20; InputSlotClass: 
D3D11_INPUT_PER_VERTEX_DATA; InstanceDataStepRate: 0 )
);

Vertices:array [0..NUMVERTICES-1] of TVERTEX =
(
  (Pos:(x:-1.0; y:-1.0; z:0); TexCoord:(x:0.0; y:1.0)),
  (Pos:(x:-1.0; y: 1.0; z:0); TexCoord:(x:0.0; y:0.0)),
  (Pos:(x: 1.0; y:-1.0; z:0); TexCoord:(x:1.0; y:1.0)),
  (Pos:(x: 1.0; y:-1.0; z:0); TexCoord:(x:1.0; y:1.0)),
  (Pos:(x:-1.0; y: 1.0; z:0); TexCoord:(x:0.0; y:0.0)),
  (Pos:(x: 1.0; y: 1.0; z:0); TexCoord:(x:1.0; y:0.0))
);
```

As you can see, I need example/explanation for dummies. I just started experimenting on GPU programming, DirectX rendering etc. Another thing is I am trying to use as few as possible external libraries. For example: I used SDL2 and tried BASS libraries for audio but later I achieved to play audio (files/streams) using *WaveAudio* on Windows and *AudioTrack* on Android which seem to work perfectly for now.

---Edit---

Creation of a TTexture with TPixelFormat.L has no sense because this one is not being converted to a DXGI Format. So currently I give up usage of TFORM3D and TPlane like in the example "03Texture".

The temporary solution is as followed(*Windows DX11*):

Using PXL library.

1. Create 1 TTexture of PixelFormat *L8* which is being converted to
   *DXGI_FORMAT_R8_UNORM* which is defined in PXL Library.
2. Set the height of the Texture to double of the picture.
3. Writing Y + U + V plane to the texture. see: https://github.com/yabadabu/dx11_video_texture
4. Using the pixelshader from the link above (3) for *FEffectTexturedL* declared in *PXL.Canvas.DX11*

The following task is to achieve the same for Android/OpenGL, after testing with different YUV types (YUV 601,709,JPEG, NV12 601, ...).

----------edit2----->

The temporary solution looks like it's working fine on windows but it's too slow again on Android OpenGL, even using the same approach as described in *EDIT1*.
The only difference between windows and android approach is that I have to copy data twice because on Android I cannot update the Texture Data from a Thread directly which is possible on Windows.
On the other hand, twice copying is not a problem on windows.

After a lot of tweaking, I am considering to leave Delphi/FMX for creating a video player, at least for mobile devices.

Answer (score 0):

I hope not to get down voted for this, but it seems there is not a good/fast enough solution for this.

It's possible to render (video) (YUV) images on a FMX Form or Component using some tweaks or libraries.
When the image size is larger than FHD, it's too slow on Android (tablet/phone). I have no Idea how fast/slow it is on iOS or on a an Android TV.

[TALVideoplayerSurface](https://github.com/Zeus64/alcinoe) ,which uses Exoplayer, is as slow/fast as other approaches.

[Exoplayer](https://exoplayer.dev/demo-application.html) examples for Android Studio is fast enough when playing UHD videos on Android.

Currently it seems like that, Android Studio is the best choice, for creating a video player.